# Would a longer PATH environment variable slow down a system?

Tags: windows-7, path, environment-variables

In Windows 7, will a long system PATH environment variable slow down the system in any noticeable/tangible way?

My system PATH variable is 45-entries deep. I have an i7 930 @ 4.2GHz, but out of general curiosity, I'm wondering if this long variable may be slowing things down. Would this mean that Windows has to continually scan those 45 entries/folders?

Comment: Remember... Windows only scans those folders when it is trying to locate an executable, but can't.

Comment: That ^ and using full paths whenever possible. I think the abuse of path is rampant, some stuff is there as a backup method, not the primary, so some of it can be removed without fault, until something else goes wrong. Myself I try and clean it some (risk), and use full paths for my own stuff always. If you think about it it doesnt have to "scan the folders" so much as all that is in the MFT, in the path situations (unlike search) there is no looking inside the files (content) so all of it is in the table of contents. Side note: another reason to have a nice clean small system partition.

Comment: @Psycogeek Thanks for your info, as well. When you say "full" paths, I assumed you're referring to path-expansion variables, such as %AppData%? (...and therefore, suggesting against using these variables)

Comment: Coldblackice: I don't think Psycogeek is recommending against using path-expansion variables (or for them).  Using them is more portable, and shouldn't trigger the use of the PATH variable to find the executable.

Comment: re your q, Windows only scans as far as it needs to. Re a comment, Writing out the full path is  a hassle. The whole benefit of having a path variable is to avoid that.  You can have a directory with bat files that run programs(not sure off hand if that helps when launching straight from start). I have that. And a directory with some small executables. Those techniques can keep it shorter.

Comment: Also, one thing that can slow it down, is if I had an entry referencing a network drive, and the network drive gets disconnected then it may just say not found file/command or it may take ages. So I put the network drive not too early in the path to lessen that when it happens. So, if a command isn't on the network drive, it should find it fast. If the network drive was early in the path, and  got disconnected and it was leaving things hanging, then even commands not on the network drive, would get a slow or no reaction.